# How do I draw long tiled paths in 2D? (Eye of the Beholder style)

Tags: graphics-programming

I'm using artwork from the following page:
http://opengameart.org/content/first-person-dungeon-crawl-art-pack

As you can see with the first artwork, the grass field is long. The floor also goes into the distance. I'm most interested in the path.

However,
The floor is really small tile-wise, much like the grass. The floor 118x22 pixels.

I'm supposing that the artwork is layered on top of each other. But how?

Is the method similar to this?
set x to 0, y -= 22
draw path
set x+=20, y -= 22
draw path
...

But as you can see, the tile isn't square, so I don't think this is correct. I'm sure there's some industry standard to doing this. Any thoughts would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this bullet point in the description of the linked art pack:

> Each tile has 13 visible positions in a rough cone shape.

And here's the floor tile within the pack (licensed CC-BY-SA 3.0):

[image: floor tiles]

So in this specific instance, nothing special needs to be done to draw these tiles right. You simply pick the right version based on where the tile is with respect to the observer, and render a normal 2D image.

As for the path itself, it is simply drawn from the sides to the center, and back to front, a la the [Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm), so they overlap properly.

As for where to draw each tile, this is very much specific to what perspective and dimensions the artwork was drawn with. You can simply load up an image editor, piece the tiles together until they are seamless, then measure the offsets. There's only 13 tiles so you can easily do this manually. Or better yet, just ask the artist, who probably knows.